# Объединение строк по одному признаку и присвоение одного значения для группы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Вопрос заключается в следующем: Есть запрос, который выводит группу строки и идентификатор товара.

`select group, idgoods from docs as ds where iddoc = 123849 order by 1`

Результат запроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо, что бы если поле group было одинаковое с соседней строкой то поле idgoods принимало значение > 0 если таковое имеется.

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это реализовать по средствам SQL?

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576

Comment: А если в группе два разных ненулевых значения - какое брать? А если в группе более 2 записей - все заполнять?

Comment: @Akina Если два не нулевых, то берется тот у которого id меньше (Хотя это не принципиально). Если более 2-х записей, заполняются все. Тоесть, если хотя-бы, у одного указано не нулевое значение, то для всех в группе будет применяться оно. Я на самом деле, хочу просто понять как это можно реализовать. Предполагаю что через iif можно выполнить, но пока не понимаю как.

Comment: *Если два не нулевых, то берется тот у которого id меньше* В упор не вижу никакого `id`. *Предполагаю что через iif можно выполнить, но пока не понимаю как.* Не-а... Вас ждёт знакомство с CROSS APPLY.

Comment: @Akina Я имел ввиду вот так: 
 https://photo-screen.ru/i/7x3EYTc6U
Если примерно представляете как решить, подскажите, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Это мне ни о чём не сказало. Вы лучше вместо своих весёлых картинок выложите CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (5-10 записей). требуемый результат для них, и будем эти данные вертеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ds.[group],
    ds.idgoods,
    ISNULL(x.idgoods, 0) AS 'NewColumn'
FROM docs as ds
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            d.[group],
            MIN(d.idgoods) AS 'idgoods'
        FROM docs d
        WHERE d.iddoc = ds.iddoc
            AND d.idgoods > 0
        GROUP BY d.[group]
    ) x ON x.[group] = ds.[group]
WHERE ds.iddoc = 123849
ORDER BY ds.[group]
```